# Распознавание готовой 3D-модели. Обучение нейронной сети

Tags: python, opencv, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Нужна помощь в поиске материалов и примеров.Извиняюсь за заведомо абстрактный вопрос и ламерство.

Появилась потребность распознать конкретного персонажа в игре на Python. Солидно прогуглив на эту тему не нашёл ничего конкретного. Есть положительная выборка изображений с 3D-модели из исходников игры и такие же отрицательные. Единственное чего нет, знаний для самобытной реализации или конкретных примеров, вместо этого нахожу распознавания лиц, карт, книг и сов с собаками и кошками. Как результат, эти примеры не заточены на решение моей задачи да и мозг я в них, как новичок, ломаю.

Мне всего лишь нужно найти выверенный образ персонажа на ограниченном количестве текстур.

Если на эту тему есть более менее разборчивый материал или примеры, не важно на каком языке, буду признателен. Также буду благодарен за доходчивые лекции или учебники на эту тематику.

Comment: Вы по скриншотам хотите искать геймера и "давать пенделя"/ "награждать" / "ставить на карандаш" ?

Comment: Просто определять, что за персонаж/моб сейчас рядом, без имени над ними, без отображаемого названия над ними, увы, надписей сверху нет, иначе было бы проще, плюс дальше хотелось бы уже распознавать не только модельку, но и анимацию

Comment: чит чтоли разрабатываете на нейронке? :)  Чего мешает взять обучающую выборку из игры, и научить нейронку классифицировать?

Comment: Вместо кошечек и собачек подкладываете мобов и персонажей... В чем проблема то? :)